# JVM Bytecode, how can I find the type of local variables?

Tags: java, bytecode

I'm working on [a fork](https://github.com/Jonatino/fernflower) of FernFlower from Jetbrains and I've been adding minor improvements to it.

One thing that really annoys me about FernFlower is that it bases the type of the local variable based on its value in bpush/spush etc. While Jode and Procyon somehow find a way to find the original value of a local variable.

Here is the original source code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int hello = 100;
    char a2 = 100;
    short y1o = 100;
    int hei = 100;

    System.out.println(a2+" "+y1o+", "+hei+", "+hello);
}
```

When decompiled with FernFlower, it outputs this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte hello = 100;
    char a2 = 100;
    byte y1o = 100;
    byte hei = 100;
    System.out.println(a2 + " " + y1o + ", " + hei + ", " + hello);
}
```

But when decompiled with Jode/Procyon it outputs the original local variable types:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
  {
    int hello = 100;
    char a2 = 'd';
    short y1o = 100;
    byte hei = 100;

    System.out.println(a2 + " " + y1o + ", " + hei + ", " + hello);
  }
```

I was wondering how is this possible because I thought no local variable type information is stored at compile time? How can I add the same functionality to FernFlower?

Comment: Is it possible that the decompilers took liberties in deciding which local type to use (e.g. `byte` versus `int`) ?

Comment: You should be able to infer it in many cases from the instructions that use those slots. Have a look at the byte code yourself, particularly the various overloads of `String.valueOf()` that are called. In this case it appears there was also some debug information, otherwise the names wouldn't have been available either.

Comment: Without debugging information there would be no LocalVariableTable in the compiled code so I don't see how the original declared type can be inferred. <confused/>

Comment: I was able to fix this myself. Please look at my answer below. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MiserableVariable I told you. From the instructions that are used on it, and the method calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after looking around and debugging I found that for some reason FernFlower decides to completely ignore some of the data in the LocalVariableTable.

Here is ferns original code for decoding the LocalVariableTable:

```
public void initContent(ConstantPool pool) throws IOException {
    DataInputFullStream data = stream();

    int len = data.readUnsignedShort();
    if (len > 0) {
        mapVarNames = new HashMap<Integer, String>(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            data.discard(4);
            int nameIndex = data.readUnsignedShort();
            data.discard(2);
            int varIndex = data.readUnsignedShort();
            mapVarNames.put(varIndex, pool.getPrimitiveConstant(nameIndex).getString());
        }
    } else {
        mapVarNames = Collections.emptyMap();
    }
}
```

If you want type information you need to add the following:

```
@Override
public void initContent(ConstantPool pool) throws IOException {
    DataInputFullStream data = stream();

    int len = data.readUnsignedShort();
    if (len > 0) {
        mapVarNames = new HashMap<Integer, String>(len);
        mapVarTypes = new HashMap<Integer, String>(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            int start  = data.readUnsignedShort();
            int end    = start + data.readUnsignedShort();
            int nameIndex = data.readUnsignedShort();
            int typeIndex = data.readUnsignedShort();
            int varIndex = data.readUnsignedShort();
            mapVarNames.put(varIndex, pool.getPrimitiveConstant(nameIndex).getString());
            mapVarTypes.put(varIndex, pool.getPrimitiveConstant(typeIndex).getString());
        }
    } else {
        mapVarNames = Collections.emptyMap();
        mapVarTypes = Collections.emptyMap();
    }
}
```

It now outputs the same code as Jode with proper variable types :)

I wonder why FernFlower chose to ignore this information.

Comment: So this code is ignoring the variable’s scopes completely? That is unlikely to work for anything but the simplest code examples…

Comment: Could you expand your response a bit more? I'm new to bytecode.

Comment: The `start` and `end` describe a range within the bytecode, where the variable is valid. Outside of this range, the same `varIndex` number might be used for a different variable, which might have a different name and type. Since you are using the `varIndex` as map key, you will record only the last encountered variable for each index. Think of code like `for(int ix=0; ix<10; ix++) {/*loop body*/} for(String str: list) {/*another loop body*/}`.  Here, `ix` and `str` have disjunct scopes and may use the same var index in the byte code.

Comment: Ah you are completely right thanks for that. I was running into an issue with bigger programs where it wouldn't know the type of variable since varIndex gets reused. I'm assuming I would need to generate a UID for each LocalVariable to ensure it doesn't overlay with other vars?

Comment: Well, you have to remember the range and use it to determine where the particular name and type is valid. This implies matching the reestablished Java source control structs with these ranges and adding blocks where necessary. When the original code already ignored the ranges, that seems to be a fundamental flaw and you’ll need to rewrite substantial parts of the decompiler to fix that…

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. FernFlower has a very crappy way of judging the variables scope and tends to reuse variable a lot when it doesn't need to. Jode has a very good way of of analyzing the scopes of variables and deciding on whether variables can share names and not conflict with one another. I intend to add the same functionality to FernFlower which is going to require me to re-write a lot of stuff.

Comment: Original Fernflower author here.

The content of LocalVariableTable doesn't get verified by VM, so obfuscators are free to store there any gibberish they like. It is dangerous to rely on this information. The only really reliable source is the code itself, that's why Fernflower is trying to deduce variable types directly from the code.

That said, there is always room for improvements, of course :)

Answer (score 5):

`.class` files optionally contain a 'LocalVariableTable' attribute for debugging purposes. If you invoke the command `javap -l <Class>.class` you can see the data if it is present.